# Programmatically modify a recently added fragment (e.g. setText to a TextView)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I add a second fragment to a view to lay on top of a first one (Google Map fragment) to show some details about clicked markers `(onInfoWindowClick(Marker)`). The new fragment is added via FragmentTransaction:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
details_fragment = new DetailsFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_container, details_fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

DetailsFragment:

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailsFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

This fragment shows different details depending on the marker being clicked, so I need to I need to set some values. For example setText to a TextView in the new fragment (inside fragment_shop.xml).

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details_title"
    ... />
```

Whatever I've tried so far gives me a null TextView (NullPointerException).
I tried accessing it by

```
((TextView) details_fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.details_title)).setText("Some Text");
```

Or

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.details_title)).setText("Some Text");
```

I tried them before and after commit with the same result. I also tried adding a tag to the fragment when adding it and using it to access by

```
fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("the_tag").getView().findViewById(R.id.details_title);
```

With the same result.

I'm surely doing something wrong, but can't figure out what. Would appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to VM4's answer I was able to solve the problem:

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    //shop contains all the info I want to set to the new fragment.
    Shop shop;
    TextView title;
    //...

    public DetailsFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);
        initView(v);
        return v;
    }

    private void initView(View v) {
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.details_title);
        title.setText(shop.getName());
        //...

    }

    public void setShop(Shop shop){
        this.shop = shop;
    }
}
```

Then I just pass shop after DetailsFragment is initiated.

```
....
details_fragment = new DetailsFragment();
details_fragment.setShop(clickedShop);
....
```

Comment: This is not really how a fragment is designed to be used and really a simple layout would be a better way to implement this.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. I have a map fragment with markers and when markers' infowindows are clicked I show their details information in a separate fragment. Mind explaining why it's not a proper use for a fragment?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something because you're cutting code out to save space it looks like you're just using it as a simple UI model. If this is the case it's more efficient to inflate a layout and set the various values from your parent map fragment. You should consider a fragment a similar component to an activity (see the design philosophy - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design). The intended way to pass data to a fragment is to use an arguments bundle rather than adding setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inflate your views in onCreateView:

```
    TextView title;
    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater
    inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.details_title);
        return v; 
    }

    public void setTitleText(String text) {
       title.setText(text); 
    }
```

Now in your activity you can: `detailsFragment.setTitleText("sometext");`

You also need to make sure that the fragment and the title View aren't null when you need them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I make sure that they're not null? They seem to be null. When setTitleText(String) is called it throws NullPointerException, but without call to that function it manages to draw the new fragment layout as it should. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well if your fragment is added neither should be null. What i meant is that you should add if (title != null) before setting text.

Comment: I tried calling the setText function from elsewhere (after the view was created and a button was clicked actually) and everything was fine. So I used calling it with postDelayed and again no problem. So it seems although the call is after add and commit the fragment is not drawn properly thus title is null?

The transaction is done in a Google Map `onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)`, might that be causing the problem?

Comment: Alright, I solved the problem by adding an instance variable to DetailsFragment and passing it through a function right after it was instantiated. (the passed variable is an object containing all info I want to set in the new fragment). So the fragment is drawn with all the info I want and no need to set them afterwards. I'll add it to my post in case it might help someone else.

I accept the answer and vote it up since it put me on the right path. Thanks again for your time.